# store flutter MediaQuery values in another class

Tags: flutter

is it possible to store flutter mediaquery values inside another .dart file with a variable and retrieve it anytime needed?

something like below?

```
class MediaQueryValues{
  function widthandheight(){
    double mediawidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double mediaheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it? You can get MediaQuery in any widget

Comment: yeah, but i have to type the whole (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) all the time, i want to save that on a single variable and use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make an extension on the `BuildContext` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
extension MediaQueryValues on BuildContext {
double get width => MediaQuery.of(this).size.width;
double get height => MediaQuery.of(this).size.height.
}
```

Now import the class in the file you want to use it in, and you can write: `context.width` and `context.height` on your `BuildContext` and it will return the screen height and width.
I believe that that is the shortest syntax.

Comment: I'm glad. Have a nice day.